# JSON parsing of finance.google.com result

Tags: json, google-finance, google-finance-api

I'm not getting how to parse finance.google.com results, i.e. I got

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"787381",
      "t":"HDFC",
      "e":"NSE",
      "l":"1,424.00",
      "l_fix":"1424.00",
      "l_cur":"&#8377;1,424.00",
      "s":"0",
      "ltt":"3:46PM GMT+5:30",
      "lt":"Sep 23, 3:46PM GMT+5:30",
      "lt_dts":"2016-09-23T15:46:54Z",
      "c":"+10.75",
      "c_fix":"10.75",
      "cp":"0.76",
      "cp_fix":"0.76",
      "ccol":"chg",
      "pcls_fix":"1413.25"
   }
]
```

when I made call to [this endpoint](http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NSE:HDFC) using httpopenConnection method, I didn't get anything returned because I couldn't find the JSON object name and i am going to use the result in my android app.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘*the json object name*’? That's JSON, parse it and you will have your data. You'll have to be more specific about what your problem is.

Comment: yeah, you're right, too early.

Comment: We're not too keen on `plz` and `tq` here, because it should not be too much effort to type "please" and "thank you". Please try to use real words when posting, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming js is your tool of choice, and you since you don't say what you're trying to do with the array, just assign to a var named `obj` and you can access it - loop as required...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Manage a JSON Object in JavaScript</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var obj = [{"id":"787381","t":"HDFC","e":"NSE","l":"1,424.00","l_fix":"1424.00","l_cur":"&#8377;1,424.00","s":"0","ltt":"3:46PM GMT+5:30","lt":"Sep 23, 3:46PM GMT+5:30","lt_dts":"2016-09-23T15:46:54Z","c":"+10.75","c_fix":"10.75","cp":"0.76","cp_fix":"0.76","ccol":"chg","pcls_fix":"1413.25"}];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj[0].id + "<br>" +
obj[0].t + "<br>" +
obj[0].e + "<br>" +
obj[0].l + "<br>" +
obj[0].l_fix + "<br>" +
obj[0].l_cur + "<br>" +
obj[0].s + "<br>" +
obj[0].ltt + "<br>" +
obj[0].lt + "<br>" +
obj[0].lt_dts + "<br>" +
obj[0].c + "<br>" +
obj[0].c_fix + "<br>" +
obj[0].cp + "<br>" +
obj[0].cp_fix + "<br>" +
obj[0].ccol + "<br>" +
obj[0].pcls_fix + "<br>"; 


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Resulting output to browser is:

```
Accessing a JSON Object in JavaScript

787381
HDFC
NSE
1,424.00
1424.00
₹1,424.00
0
3:46PM GMT+5:30
Sep 23, 3:46PM GMT+5:30
2016-09-23T15:46:54Z
+10.75
10.75
0.76
0.76
chg
1413.25
```

Comment: That's not JSON, though. And where, exactly, is the ‘parsing’?!

Comment: Still no JSON. And what are you answering?! OP hasn't even asked a question.

Comment: Yep, that's part of the issue.